# Understanding differences between indexing solutions

Tags: python-3.x

I am a self-taught newbie looking to understand the difference between the two below, and what would make one optimal over the other. Thanks in advance for your help!

Here are the instructions I am trying to follow:

Write a function flipside(s), which takes in a string s and returns a string
whose first half is s's second half and whose second half is s's first half.
If len(s) (the length of s) is odd, the first half of the input string should have one fewer character than the second half.

SOLUTION 1

```
def flipside(s):
    x = int(len(s)/2)
    print(s[x:len(s)]+s[0:x])
```

SOLUTION 2

```
def flipside(s):
    length = len(s)
    mid = int(length / 2)
    return f"{s[mid:length]}{s[0:mid]}"
```

Comment: `print` and `return` are _fundamentally_ different. Try this: `print(flipside([1,2,3,4]))` with both functions and compare the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
def flipside(s):
    x = len(s) // 2
    return s[x:] + s[:x]
```

In both cases You use slices, so in my opinion their is no major difference in optimality, from indexing point of view.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me understand what I was trying to ask!

Answer (score 0):

As ForceBru commented

> `print` and `return` are *fundamentally* different.

And the instruction said,
*...string s and **returns a string** whose first...*

so, I'll use solution 2.

```
def flipside(s):
    length = len(s)
    mid = int(length / 2)
    return f"{s[mid:length]}{s[0:mid]}"
```

since it returns, not prints the result